# WWW:Selenium open perl application replacing other windows

Tags: perl, selenium, cgi

I have a selenium perl script using CPAN WWW::Selenium.

The problem is that when I Open my application it will not open it. however when I try google it's fine. I can query the and page and so on. 
However when I open my page The additional windows close and the main page is replaced with my login page.

What can I do? I'm confused as what to do.

The index.html page is a redirect to a perl cgi script. could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had more success with http://search.cpan.org/~aivaturi/Selenium-Remote-Driver/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm

```
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;

my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver;
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
print $driver->get_title();
$driver->quit();
```

More specifically, Selenium creates a whole new session when you use it so the mechanism you use to login will not be available to it and you will need to automate logging in again

updated to add details on selecting a select/combo box. The find_element(s) methods return objects of type Selenium::Remote::WebElement http://search.cpan.org/~chowes/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.17/lib/Selenium/Remote/WebElement.pm

```
use Test::More tests=>3;
use_ok 'Selenium::Remote::Driver';

foreach (qw( phantomjs )){
  note $_;

  my $driver = new_ok('Selenium::Remote::Driver' => [ browser_name => $_, proxy=>{proxyType=> 'direct'}]);

  ok $driver->get('http://www.websitedatabases.com/php_form_maker/html_forms/example-10.html');
  $driver->set_implicit_wait_timeout(100);

  my $combo = $driver->find_elements('//select[@name="what-to-do"]//option');

  map{ note $_->get_value } @$combo;

  $combo->[4]->click;
  note '1 '. $driver->find_element('//select[@name="what-to-do"]')->get_value;

  $combo->[0]->click;
  note '2 ' . $driver->find_element('//select[@name="what-to-do"]')->get_value;
}
```

Comment: I am currently using this but sleecting elements form a combobox is impossible. How are you selecting comboboxes.